# How do we add the spot bulging effect in css?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how we can do this spot bulging effect as done in this site: https://koding.com/ 
If you check the video section, you can see the green circles has got a nice css animation repeating in same interval. I checked online for the similar tutorials but couldn't find any.

They used this class: `span.intro-marker`
Does anybody know how to create this effect?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and inspecting in firebug?

Comment: Yes, but I got failed. That's why I checked the tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to know everything about specific element of any page, right click and click the "**Inspect Element**".

Most browsers have this feature. It will tell you the information about that specific element you wanted in detailed manner. Here it is :

```
span.intro-marker {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at center center , #1AAF5D 50%, rgba(26, 175, 93, 0.2) 57%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 2px solid #1AAF5D;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 52px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) 0s;
    width: 52px;
    z-index: 10;
}
span.intro-marker.in {
    transform: scale(1);
}
span.intro-marker.in:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: 5s linear 3s normal none infinite homeMarkers;
    -webkit-animation: 5s linear 3s normal none infinite homeMarkers;
    background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at center center , rgba(26, 175, 93, 0) 70%, #1AAF5D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #1AAF5D;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    height: 52px;
    left: -2px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    width: 52px;
}
@keyframes homeMarkers {
  5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  27% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes homeMarkers {
  5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  27% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes homeMarkers {
  5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  27% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZb7X/8/), tested in firefox

Comment: A jsfiddle would be great

Comment: @user1012181 Yes, do one and lets us know how it looks. If you get issues with it we might be able to help.

Comment: @pellePenna http://jsfiddle.net/FZb7X/ here it is.. the animation is not taking place

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FZb7X/8/

Comment: It is properly shown in firefox

Answer (score 2):

The below fiddle/code should give you a decent starting point for you to then tweak as needed

## **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBwY4/1/)**

HTML

```
<span class="point"><span class="ripple"></span><span>
```

CSS

```
.point, .ripple {
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:100%;
    height:55px;
    width:55px;
}
.ripple {
    position:absolute;
    transition:all 1.2s ease;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #1AAF5D, inset 0px 0px 23px #8AF2B7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #1AAF5D, inset 0px 0px 23px #8AF2B7;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #1AAF5D, inset 0px 0px 23px #8AF2B7;
}
.point {
    position:relative;
    border: 2px solid #1AAF5D;
    background:rgba(26, 175, 93, 0);
}
.point:after {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:100%;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    background:#1AAF5D;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
}
.point:hover .ripple {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving actual example from scratch for learning point